# Sending Additional Parameters to Token in Web API with oauth2 and AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I've got an application written in AngularJS that contacts a Web API for authentication via oauth 2. Everything is working well with that core piece, but I need to pass in additional parameters to evaluate the login (clientID) and setup a remember me type functionality (remember).

From the Angular side, it would look something like this:

```
    var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + form.username + "&password=" + form.password + "&clientID=" + clientID + "&remember=" + form.remember;

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.post(serviceBase + 'token', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).success(function (response) {
```

Any thoughts as the best way to capture those values once I'm processing the token through Startup.cs and SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider.cs? Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`, you can retrieve the OWIN request from `OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext` and extract the custom parameter you need by calling `ReadFormAsync()`.

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    var form = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();

    if (string.Equals(form["remember"], "true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // Add custom logic to handle the "remember me" case.
    }
}
```

That said, adding custom (i.e non-standard) parameters is usually discouraged, specially if they are mandatory. Note that you don't need to use a custom `clientID` parameter, as there's already a standard equivalent: `client_id`.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks for the assist. I overlooked the client_id so that is good to know. So if adding non-standard parameters is discouraged, how would you recommend passing that true/false value across to set that remember me functionality?

Comment: IMHO, a "remember me" thing doesn't make much sense in the marvelous world of tokens. What does it do exactly?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the remember me feature really, but the my client wants it. Basically, the token is set to expire after 24 hours by default and remember me extends that expiration value to 30 days.

Comment: Using long-lived or persistent access tokens is really not a good idea. Instead, have you considered using refresh tokens?

Comment: I haven't explored refresh tokens much. I'll give them a look and see if I can accomplish the same thing with them.

Comment: for non async method one can use like this,
`(context.Request.ReadFormAsync().Result as Microsoft.Owin.FormCollection)["CustomField1"]` to get the value from custom field