# Pass extra parameters with token header

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I create a web API with authentication  with token 
as

http://localhost:25419/token

username : username
password :password
grant_type : password

so the data returned as

```
{
    "access_token": "token data",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 86400
}
```

now i need to add extra parameters when i call the token 
as for example storeId and return the the store name fore example

to be as 
http://localhost:25419/token?storeId=100

is it possible i tried but give me bad request

Thanks

Comment: the http://localhost:25419/token is POST or GET?

Comment: Try to send additional data with username and password to ```/token``` endpoint like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34520374/1443361).

Answer (score 0):

A token endpoint has one job, to create a token based on the username / password you're sending if accepted as valid data.

This can link into your own membership system, because once you have the username, you should be able to find out which store it is without having to send anything through to the token endpoint.

Instead, you validate the username and password, then go and retrieve the store id and name and add the name to the token as a claim. You can add other bits of information as well to the tokens via claims, depending on what you need.

You can read more about claims here : https://jwt.io/introduction/ or check whatever library you are using for your JWT token system